# Easiest and most affordable webhost to transfer and host the domain of an existing .php website to another existing domain name?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, wordpress, domain-transfer, transfer

I've had a friend of mine create a .php website for me that he hosts on a personal raspberry pi server.

It looks fantastic and works great. However, I already have a website and domain that was hosted via WordPress.com that I need to transfer this new .php website to. I've discovered that WordPress.com is very expensive to host on compared to other webhosting service providers and want to switch webhosts as a result.

I've already learned how to transfer domains to another registrar on WordPress. https://wordpress.com/support/domains/transfer-domain-registration/

My question is this: What webhosting provider would be the cheapest and best to host this new website on? (Bonus points if it allows me to make edits to the website in an intuitive way for a non-programmer like myself, though that isn't required.) And what will my friend, who already has a fantastic 100% working version of the new website running, need to provide me in order that I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question will be closed as it asks for recommendations, which is against the community guidelines https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask